# How Can I find my database host name?

Tags: php, mysql

Im realy new into this php and android online database thing,So I really ask to somebody to fix my problem.

Im using mysqli_connection and I need my host name for this query ;

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
```

But the problem is I dont know what is my host my phpMyAdmin site look like this
   https://hike.veridyen.com:2083/
and I'm entering my site from this url;

http://dobo.us/atakan/

so what is my host name please ?

Comment: You are using cPanel admin-interface. You'll find the needed information there, for connecting to the mysql-database. It should be available under site-settings, site-information, database-information or similar options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a shared hosting it should be located as follow:

> After creating your database, you can find its details, including its
>   hostname, in your control panel.
>
> Log in to your GoDaddy account.
>
> 1. Click Web Hosting.
> 2. Next to the hosting account you want to use, click Manage.
> 3. In the Databases area, click MySQL or MSSQL depending on the database type for which you want the host name.
> 4. From your list of databases, click Actions next to the database you want to use, and then click Details.
>
> Your database's details displays including its username, host name,
>   and a link to reset its password.

Instructions above are for GoDaddy, but should give you a general sense of direction.

Comment: Thanks guys,I have an idea at least now.I know where to look.I know its simple and bad question but I had to ask thanks

Comment: You are welcome, I hope the answer helps you to  find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

For SiteGround, use 'localhost'

Answer (score 0):

For cPpanel:

Log into your cPanel. Click the Server Information link in the General Information section. You will then see your Server Name listed along with additional information about your server.

Or

if the database is hosted on the same server where the application is hosted use the hostname as localhost , if the database is hosted different server ask the server owner or provider for the hostname.